# git submodules. Detached state vs master

Tags: git, git-submodules

Lets say i have two repos R1 and R2 which are using one common submodule.

When time comes to build any of them, i see two possible ways

- Keeping submodule in detached state on a specific commit
- Always updating it to latest change using $git pull

Which practice is the best and most safe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Both repositories have an independent reference to a commit in the submodule repository. If you want to change the commit, you have to commit the changed submodule commit id in the parent repository.

> Keeping submodule in detached state on a specific commit

There is *always* a certain commit checked out in a submodule. There might be some branch pointing to that commit, or there might not be. All the parent repository knows is the id of the commit that should currently be checked out.

> Always updating it to latest change using $git pull

It's entirely up to you *when* you do this. It's usually done when the parent repository needs updated features from the submodule, or important bugfixes have been made. Otherwise, there is no need to update.

I advise to do some further reading on submodules, for example in the [pro git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).